# How long should it take to process big files in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-io, node-streams

I am not used to working with big files but I was wondering how long does it approximately takes to read and write in node.js when using files that are 2-3GB big or ~ 7.5 million lines.

my current implementation takes about ~ 12 minutes or 737859.276ms

I know that it's hard to approximate and depends on context but I wanted to make sure if it could be done faster.

```
function LogParser(filePath, outputFile, cb) {
  try {
    const rl = createInterface({
      input: createReadStream(filePath),
      crlfDelay: Infinity,
    });
    writer.pipe(createWriteStream(outputFile));
    rl.on('line', (line) => {
      // Gets line and splits it by " - " where the ip is the first value
      const IPAddress = line.split(' - ')[0];
      const locationData = lookup(IPAddress); // translate to data object with region and country and city
      const userAgentData = parser(line); // get userAgent data
      const result = {
// object with data inside
      };
      writer.write(result)
    });

    rl.on('close', () => {
      writer.end()
    });
  } catch (e) {
    throw new Error(e.message);
  }
```

Comment: I suspect the lookup() function is expensive and that the time for it dwarfs any time taken up by the reading and writing. To check this, you should temporarily replace it with a hardcoded example value.

Comment: Thanks, you are right! I am using third party libraries to get user and location data, and once I hardcoded it, it was only 12 seconds. Incredible! There may be a lot of duplicate data, so I will try caching some to avoid duplicate requests, but other than that, is there anything you would recommend to optimize further?

Comment: Not really, without digging into that third party library code. Caching same-IP requests is going to pay off some though yes.